# Firemonkey keyboard not sugest password

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I would like to know if there is any function in Delphi FMX to show the saved passwords of an application on the keyboard when the user is in the password field?

I did several searches and found nothing

If anyone has already gone through this and can help me, I would appreciate it, because I only found it in Android Studio about... the google api that stores this data...